# capturing empty output returned from commandline and display some message if its empty

Tags: c, stdio, fgets

I need to print something in my window when the script "**check.sh**" returns nothing, means validation when no output from the script is returned.

check.sh contains nothing in it. It is simply a blank sh file that returns nothing when executed. I am testing with an empty sh file (I cannot show u the exact script that is why).

What I want to print is some message like "configure some thing" through C when check.sh returns nothing.

I checked buffer **line(check in the module below)** with "\n","\r","\0",NULL.. I don't know what it is taking when the script returns nothing

I'll be calling the module as **execute_command("sh check.sh")**

Here is my module

```
char *execute_command(char *command)
{
    FILE *fpipe;
    char line[1024]="";
    //char *line = (char*)malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
    int i =0;

    if ( !(fpipe = (FILE*)popen(command,"r")) )
    {  // If fpipe is NULL
        perror("Problems with pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ( fgets( line, sizeof line, fpipe))
    {
        // printf("%s", line);
    }

    while(line[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(line[i]==' ')
        {
            line[i]=',';
        }
        i++;
    }
    pclose(fpipe);
    printf("%s",line); // This is where i want to know what the buffer has when the script returns nothing 
    return(line);
}
```

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your question. In particular, indent your code better: as it is it's incomprehensible. Otherwise people (for example me) won't help you.

Comment: Please leave a note about the solution, could you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

According to this **[fgets](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/)** man page, if end-of-file occurs before any characters are read, it returns `NULL` and the buffer contents remain unchanged.